# extract the first two characters from a list of names in r

Tags: r, string

The data frame df1 contains two columns: id and list_names

```
id <- seq(1,5)
list_names <- c("john", 
                "adam, sally", 
                "rebecca", 
                "zhang, mike, antonio", 
                "mark, henry, scott, john, steve, jason, nancy")

df1 <- data.frame(id, list_names)
```

I need to add an additional column that contains the first two characters extracted from every name.

The new data set would look like

[image]

Note that the number of names in each row does not need to be specified as it could be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_extract_all` to extract two characters after the word boundary

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(two_chars = str_extract_all(list_names, "\\b[a-z]{2}")  %>%
                            map_chr(toString))
#  id                                    list_names                  two_chars
#1  1                                          john                         jo
#2  2                                   adam, sally                     ad, sa
#3  3                                       rebecca                         re
#4  4                          zhang, mike, antonio                 zh, mi, an
#5  5 mark, henry, scott, john, steve, jason, nancy ma, he, sc, jo, st, ja, na
```

---

Or using `gsub`

```
gsub("\\b([a-z]{2})[^,]+", "\\1", df1$list_names)
#[1] "jo"                         "ad, sa"                     "re"                         "zh, mi, an"                
#[5] "ma, he, sc, jo, st, ja, na"
```

Comment: Great. Thanks! do you mind sharing what's the explanation of $"\\b[a-z]{2}"$?

Comment: @user9292 The `\\b` is word boundary, we select `[a-z]` (lower case letters) `{2}` two following a word boundary iin str_extract_all i.e. every 2 letter (lower case)

Answer (score 2):

In a for loop split each observation with `strsplit()` on `', '` then `substr` the first two characters, and then `paste` back together:

```
for(g in df1$list_names){
  print(
   paste(substr(unlist(strsplit(g, ', ')),1,2), collapse = ', ')
  )
}

[1] "jo"
[1] "ad, sa"
[1] "re"
[1] "zh, mi, an"
[1] "ma, he, sc, jo, st, ja, na"
```

or you can one line this with `sapply`:

```
df1$new_list_names = sapply(df1$list_names, function(g) paste(substr(unlist(strsplit(as.character(g), ', ')),1,2), collapse = ', '))

> df1
  id                                    list_names             new_list_names
1  1                                          john                         jo
2  2                                   adam, sally                     ad, sa
3  3                                       rebecca                         re
4  4                          zhang, mike, antonio                 zh, mi, an
5  5 mark, henry, scott, john, steve, jason, nancy ma, he, sc, jo, st, ja, na
```